# Facebook JavaScript SDK and PHP SDK not intergrating like before since their platform updates

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

Since Facebook updated its [developers roadmap changes](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/12/05/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/) yesterday, my site has major problems as it has Facebook Login dependency.

I believe the problem is my Facebook JS SDK provided below:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=ID";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        var button;
        var userInfo;

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({ 
                appId: 'ID', //change the appId to your appId
                channelUrl : '//www.DOMAIN.com/channel.html', // Channel File
                status: true, 
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                oauth: true});

           showLoader(false);

           function updateButton(response) {
                button       =   document.getElementById('fb-auth');
                userInfo     =   document.getElementById('user-info');

                if (response.authResponse) {
                    //user is already logged in and connected
                    FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                        login(response, info);
                    });

                    button.onclick = function() {
                        FB.logout(function(response) {
                            logout(response);
                        });
                        $.post('scripts/logout.php',{ facebook_id:response.authResponse.userID } ,  function(data) {
                            //kill sessions
                        }); 
                  };
                } else {
                    //user is not connected to your app or logged out
                    button.innerHTML = '';
                    button.onclick = function() {
                        showLoader(false);
                        FB.login(function(response) {
                            if (response.authResponse) {
                                FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                                    login(response, info);
                              });   
                            } else {
                                //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                                showLoader(false);
                            }
                            window.location.href='/user/index.php';                             
                        }, {scope:'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_about_me'});   
                    }
                    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
                      if (response.status === 'connected') {
                        window.top.location = '../user/index.php';
                      }
                    });
                }
            }

            // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
            FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
            //FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);    
            // FB login insert/update               

            // Additional init code here
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // connected
                    FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                            getLoginStatus(response, info);
                        });
                    if (response.authResponse.userID) {
                        $.post('scripts_profile/init.php',{ facebook_id:response.authResponse.userID } ,  function(data) {
                            //Good
                        });  
                    } else {
                        //Nothing   
                    }
                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    // not_authorized
                    login();
                } else {
                    // not_logged_in
                    login();
                }
            });             
        };
        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
           if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));

    </script>
```

My site also has Facebook PHP SDK that intergrates with the Facebook JS SDK.

Since Facebooks updates, the JS SDK is not intergrating as before with the PHP causing inconncistencies.

For example, on my site if a user is logged they the header differently to a visitor. So as per FB PHP SDK:

```
if (!my_profile) {
    //user header
} else {
    //visitor header
}
```

Since the update, once logged in, a logged in user needs to refresh the page to view it as he should... and not simply by visiting it. As soon as I try to visit that page directly (by clicking on a link or by typing the url) it shows me as logged out!

I've spend the last 10 hours working around it and Im trully lost. Your help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm experiencing the same problems as you and so are others. Seems it's a bug with the latest policy changes.

See here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/238039849657148

Comment: This has now been fixed by updating to the latest version of the PHP-SDK.

Comment: thank you so much!!! Problem sovled since updating my base_facebook.php files to their latest update this morning v3.2.2